# Web colors: how to compensate for differences in monitors

Tags: website-design, color, monitor

This question has to do with color in the context of web pages.

Computer monitors and mobile screens can vary a lot in their color rendering, meaning that a given color on one monitor can look much different on another monitor.

For example, some greens and teals may look pleasant on one monitor but look sickly yellowish on others.

Are there certain web colors that are "safer" than others (NOT to be confused with the outdated practice of using "web-safe color palette")?

Or do you just create the web design on a calibrated monitor and know that's all you can do?

Answer (score 11):

You can not compensate. Obsessing about the perfect hue is largely irrelevant for most audiences. All you can really do is make your part and use a monitor that is calibrated or emulating sRGB.

Average user does not really have a choice on the color they are displayed. They can have bad, cheap, damaged or old panels. Since the color effects are global no color is likely to show better than others. But due to human relative color perception this should work out quite well nonetheless.

You might want to stay away from choices that are very sensitive to value changes. Use bolder colors.