# CMYK in notebook looks different in other media

Tags: color, cmyk, rgb, color-profile, calibration

I usually do my works in Photoshop in an Asus notebook. The problem that I'm having is that whenever I save a picture in CMYK format it looks fine everywhere I try to visualize it in my Asus, but when I try to print it or when I transfer it to other devices like my mobile or other computers, it gets oversaturated.

[image: This is the image as I see it on Photoshop (well, kinda, it's RGB, but you get the level of saturation I'm talking about. Pretend it's CMYK.)]

This is the image as I see it on my Asus.

[image: And this is how I see it when I transfer to other devices or when I print it.]

And this is how I see it when I transfer to other devices or when I print it.

I know there are a lot of differences between colour schemes in CMYK and in RGB (as supposed in a screen), but at least in Photoshop I should see the image exactly how it would look like when printed, otherwise designing in CMYK would be useless.
I have looked through questions like this [How can I make sure that my on-screen colors are consistent?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71693/how-can-i-make-sure-that-my-on-screen-colors-are-consistent) but none of the solutions given fully solved my problem (my notebook screen isn't provided with settings as to calibrate it so finely). Should I look at my graphics card configuration? Should I update my graphics card driver? Should I change my graphics board? Should I throw my notebook away and buy a new one?

Comment: Different types of displays use different technology to show light and color so there is a wide range of difference between screens. They make color analyzers to use on your screen to calibrate it. Ideally the output is also calibrated to a printer so everything matches. Aside from that your Asus display looks washed out, not bright or saturated. You might want to adjust the settings to make the image appear more like it does n other machines and  print.

Answer (score 1):

Not all applications support the proper display of CMYK images - that includes some web browsers and image viewers.

Unless someone has software on a device which will display them properly there is nothing you can do about it.

If you want to share images on the web or on other devices where there is no suitable software, then use RGB images, not CMYK.  CMYK is for print. RGB is for the web, and ordinary people who don't have graphic design software installed on their devices.

The best you can do is to save images in RGB, and to apply the sRGB colour profile which is the standard for the web.  Even so, different devices will still display images differently - there is nothing you can do about that, unless you were to get everyone who views them to calibrate their displays with hardware calibration devices. Obviously, that's entirely impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can only do so much. If you have, as you say, followed all the solutions in that thread you are at a loss.

You are limited by the technology available to you. A MacBook's retina screen will always look better than a simple 24" monitor.

Source: Working on multiple set-ups, triple monitor setups running off of a MacBook.